# Generic type lost for member of raw type

Tags: java, generics

I have found a strange behavior when working with generics.

In this class `Foo<T>`, the `strings` member doesn't have anything to do with `T`:

```
package test;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Foo<T> {
    ArrayList<String> strings;

    T getSome() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The class is used in main:

```
package test;

public class Main {

    public static void main() {
        Foo<Integer> intFoo = new Foo<>();
        Integer i = intFoo.getSome();
        String s1 = intFoo.strings.get(0);

        Foo rawFoo = new Foo();
        Object o = rawFoo.getSome();
        String s2 = rawFoo.strings.get(0); // Compilation error on this line
    }
}
```

The compilation error is "incompatible types. required: String found: Object".

It appears that Java forgets the `String` type argument to `ArrayList` when raw type of `Foo` is used.

My java version is 1.7.0_21

Comment: This is completely normal. Raw types are completely raw (all members). Please search for similar questions.

Comment: Raw types are meant for backward compatibility. From the [java tutorial on raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html): "When using raw types, you essentially get pre-generics behavior". The raw type for Foo would not be backward-compatible if it had a generic member (even if it does not depend on T)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply put, because `rawFoo` is raw, its non-static members also become raw.

This is outlined in [JLS §4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> More precisely, a raw type is defined to be one of:
>
> - The reference type that is formed by taking the name of a generic type declaration without an accompanying type argument list.
> - An array type whose element type is a raw type.
> - A non-static member type of a raw type R that is not inherited from a superclass or superinterface of R.

Note the last bullet.

Comment: The last bullet is actually referring to inner classes (non-static member *type*), not fields.