Why is there a compile error in generic class method reference?
Why will functionDemo3.test produce a compile error, that is "incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String"? While functionDemo.test and functionDemo2.test do not.
import java.util.function.Function;

public class FunctionTemplateDemo<T> {

    public Object sayHello(String name) {
        return "hello " + name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FunctionTemplateDemo<String> functionDemo = new FunctionTemplateDemo<String>();
        functionDemo.test(functionDemo::sayHello);

        FunctionTemplateDemo<?> functionDemo2 = new FunctionTemplateDemo<Object>();
        functionDemo2.test(functionDemo::sayHello);

        FunctionTemplateDemo functionDemo3 = new FunctionTemplateDemo<Object>();
        functionDemo3.test(functionDemo::sayHello);
    }

    private void test(Function<String, Object> function) {
        Object hello = function.apply("hello");
        System.out.println("say: " + hello);
    }
}


I'm unable to search for a duplicate question right now on Stack Overflow, but I'm sure there is (at least) one. The term to search for is "raw type".

I think Yshavit is right, you can't say you're using generics on the right hand side, then on the left hand side use the raw type.  Both types must be raw or it's a bust.

What do you mean by "why"? What kind of answer are you looking for?

Also check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248616/generic-type-lost-for-member-of-raw-type. Basically, you "loose" all the generic types, including Function<String, Object>, which becomes just Function (so the first argument is an Object, not a String anymore).

functionDemo works because FunctionTemplateDemo explicitly defines the generic type, and the method reference fits the expected function signature.
functionDemo2 works because FunctionTemplateDemo<?> uses a wildcard, allowing flexibility without interfering with the function signature.
functionDemo3 fails because using a raw type disables type safety, leading the compiler to infer the wrong types (Object instead of String), causing a mismatch in the method reference signature.
The raw type (FunctionTemplateDemo) strips away the generic type information, causing the compiler to interpret the test method as expecting Function<Object, Object>. This is incompatible with the method reference functionDemo::sayHello, which is of type Function<String, Object>.
The key issue is that Function<Object, Object> and Function<String, Object> are not interchangeable because the input type (String vs Object) is different. The raw type causes the compiler to infer an Object where a String is expected, leading to a type mismatch.
Changing the raw type to a proper generic type fixes the problem:
FunctionTemplateDemo<Object> functionDemo3 = new FunctionTemplateDemo<>();
functionDemo3.test(functionDemo::sayHello);

